# Find the Range of Function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra

What is the range of the map $\mathbb{C}^m\to\mathbb{C}^m$,
$$(z_1,\ldots,z_m)\mapsto (b_1,\ldots,b_m),$$
where $b_k=\prod_{j\neq k}(z_j-z_k)$ for $1\leq k\leq m$ ?

Comment: Why the FA tag?

Comment: What do you mean by range of points in $P^{m-1}$ ?

Comment: Same question with $\mathbb{R}^m$ seems to be interesting too.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Your edit seems to have changed the meaning of the original question, which was asking explicitly about the range of the map viewed as taking values in complex projective space

Comment: To the original poster: what did you mean in your original question: complex affine space or complex projective space?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: If this is so, I am sorry, and I hope the author will restore the original version. Original statement was difficult for me to understand, and I proposed my interpretation.

Comment: In the original question it was asked to describe the range of $[a_1,...a_m]=[1/b_1,...,1/b_m]$ in projective space $P^{m-1}$. What on your opinion this means?